# Spring Data Streaming query throws no transaction error on JBoss 7 with JTA

Tags: java, spring, jboss, spring-data, jboss7.x

I'm trying to integrate Spring Data with my Java EE app. I am deploying this to JBoss 7.0. I have an EJB that calls a data access object operation, but keeps on throwing the following exception even though my EJB has a running container-managed transaction.

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: You're trying to execute a streaming query method without a surrounding transaction that keeps the connection open so that the Stream can actually be consumed. Make sure the code consuming the stream uses @Transactional or any other way of declaring a (read-only) transaction.

[image]

Did I miss something? Or is it not possible to integrate container-managed transaction with Spring Data on a Java EE app?

Comment: You must call personRepository.stream() in a method that has a transaction. If the caller is a CDI Bean annotate the method with @Transactional as stated in the error message.

Comment: I don't think `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` will work in a CDI environment. I think it needs Spring AOP which is not possible, at least in my current setup with EJB/CDI.

Comment: No you must add the CDI @Transaction annotation if it is a CID bean.

Comment: The question is if mixing Spring and CDI is a good idea. Deltaspike Data would be a better choice for your setup: http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/data.html

Comment: @simas_ch EJB methods are wrapped with transaction by default, unless transaction management is set to `BEAN`. So there is no need to specify `@javax.transaction.Transactional`. Also, looking at the screenshot, transaction status is `0`, implying transaction is active.

Comment: Can you provide some source code of your integeration? It should look like this: https://github.com/mstahv/jpa-helper-libraries

Comment: The thing is, all other operations (saving, updating, deleting entities as well as entity retrieval other than by streaming) are running well.

Answer (score 1):

How are you trying to integrate Spring Data with the EJB?

You must create the repository with a factory and pass the EntityManager:

```
@Stateless
public class ExampleBean {

  @PersistenceContext
  EntityManager entityManager;

  public Example findExample(String name){
       JpaRepositoryFactory jpaRepositoryFactory=new JpaRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
       ExampleRepository repository = jpaRepositoryFactory.getRepository(ExampleRepository.class);
       return repository.findOne(name);

  }
}
```

Comment: I used Spring Data's CDI extension, making repositories as CDI beans, and are injectable within CDI container. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpd.misc.cdi-integration

Comment: First why do you down vote my answer? The suggested solution is correct and works. And in your question you didn't mention CDI integration.